# Use PHPMyAdmin to manage table relationship and add data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a total newbie for php and mysql. Now I want to create a simple website for practice. I have created two tables named `user_info` and `acct_info`.

The `primary key` for `user_info` is the `user_id`. There is another `user_id` in `acct_info` as well.

I have relate these two tables by linking the `user_id` (referenced key is the `user_id` in `user_info`, that of `acct_info` is `foreign key`). However, when new user register new account on my website, new data will be added into the `user_info` table, but nothing happened in `acct_info` table.

### Could anyone provide me some advice?

Sorry for not stating the problem clearly.
I have created a new user, however, data is added into user_info table but nothing in acct_info table. I thought if I build relationship between these two tables, for example, I create new user, then data like user_id and all those default data should be also added into acct_info table. I wrote php codes in my registration page to add user information into user_info table but I didn't do it to add data into acct_table. If I need to write codes for acct_table, what is the purpose to relate these two tables?

### Sorry for asking dummy questions... :)

This is the php code for the data adding part:

```
if($reachByPOST && $okay == true && $NotExistingUsername == true && $NotExistingEmail == true) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_info SET user_id = '',user_name = '".$_POST['username']."',password = '".$_POST['password']."',email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid;
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO acct_info SET user_id = '".$userid."'";
    $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

However, I got error saying $userid is undifiend...I just have no idea on how to add data into acct_info table...By the way the user_id is auto_increment in user_info table, it is generated automatically, not post input by user.

Comment: Could you post your code where you insert data to the tables

Comment: What is PHPMyAdmin doing here? My advice, review your php code or post some code excerpt (showing the revelant parts)

Comment: that is because you are not inserting to it, you will also need to insert data there. please post ur code

Answer (score 0):

if you insert in user_info, it has no affect to acct_info.

But if you insert into acct_info, there should exist user_id in user_info(pri key), which will be inserted in acct_info.

Try to insert random data in acct_info.... If you don't have right user_id, you should get error.